# Populate drop down with MVC EF using AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've recently started using AngularJS. I've a Drop Down in my HTML which I want to populate using Database. But I can't find a proper solution inside a controller on how to populate it. Below is my C# code:-

```
 public JsonResult GetLocList()
    {
      IEnumerable<LocationTbl> ie = (from d in db.LocationTbls
                                      select d).ToList();
      //var ret = db.LocationTbls.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.LocName }).ToList();
      return Json(ie,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My HTML is :-

```
 <tr>
    <td>
      Location :
    </td>
    <td>
      <select ng-model="CustLoc" ng-options="l.locname for l in location">
      <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
      </select>
      <span class="error" ng-show="(f1.uCustLoc.$dirty || f1.$submitted) && f1.uCustLoc.$error.required">Location required!</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I've a CustForm.js file for Angular in which I want to populate Drop Down as:-

```js
angular.module('custFormApp', [])
        .controller('custDetailController', function ($scope, FileUploadService) {
            debugger;
            //Variables
            $scope.Message = "";
            $scope.FileInvalidMessage = "";
            $scope.SelectedFileForUpload = null;
            $scope.CustName = "";
            $scope.CustDoB = "";
            $scope.CustPhone = "";
            $scope.CustEMail = "";
            $scope.CustDescription = "";
            $scope.CustGender = "";

            $scope.IsFormSubmitted = false;
            $scope.IsFileValid = false;
            $scope.IsFormValid = false;

            //Form Validation
            $scope.$watch("f1.$valid", function (isValid) {
                $scope.IsFormValid = isValid;
                //GetLocList();
            });

            //File Validation
            $scope.ChechFileValid = function (file) {
                var isValid = false;
                if ($scope.SelectedFileForUpload != null) {
                    if ((file.type == 'image/png' || file.type == 'image/jpeg' || file.type == 'image/gif' || file.type == 'image/jpg') && file.size <= (512 * 1024)) {
                        $scope.FileInvalidMessage = "";
                        isValid = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.FileInvalidMessage = "Selected file is Invalid. (only file type png,jpg, jpeg and gif and 512 kb size allowed)";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $scope.FileInvalidMessage = "Image required!";
                }
                $scope.IsFileValid = isValid;
            };

            //File Select event 
            $scope.selectFileforUpload = function (file) {
                $scope.SelectedFileForUpload = file[0];
            }

            //Save File
            $scope.SaveFile = function () {
                $scope.IsFormSubmitted = true;
                $scope.Message = "";
                $scope.ChechFileValid($scope.SelectedFileForUpload);
                if ($scope.IsFormValid && $scope.IsFileValid) {
                    FileUploadService.UploadFile($scope.CustName, $scope.CustDoB, $scope.CustPhone, $scope.CustEMail, $scope.CustDescription, $scope.CustGender, $scope.SelectedFileForUpload).then(function (d) {
                        alert(d.Message);
                        ClearForm();
                    }, function (e) {
                        alert(e);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $scope.Message = "Please Fill Required Details";
                }
            };

            //Clear form 
            function ClearForm() {
                $scope.CustName = "";
                $scope.CustDoB = "";
                $scope.CustPhone = "";
                $scope.CustEMail = "";
                $scope.CustDescription = "";
                $scope.CustGender = "";
                //as 2 way binding not support for File input Type so we have to clear in this way
                //you can select based on your requirement
                angular.forEach(angular.element("input[type='file']"), function (inputElem) {
                    angular.element(inputElem).val(null);
                });

                $scope.f1.$setPristine();
                $scope.IsFormSubmitted = false;
            }
            
            function GetLocList() {
                $http({
                    method: 'Get',
                    url: '/Home/GetLocList'
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.location = data;
                    alert(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
                });
            }();

            //function getList() {
            //    debugger;
            //    var arrLocation = new Array();
            //    $http.get("/Home/LocList/").success(function (data) {

            //        $.map(data, function (item) {
            //            arrLocation.push(item.Id);
            //            arrLocation.push(item.LocName);
            //        });

            //        $scope.list = arrLocation;
            //    }).error(function (status) {
            //        alert(status);
            //    });
            //}

            //function getList($scope, $http) {
            //    $http.get("WebService/LocationService.asmx/GetLocation")
            //    .then(function (response) {
            //        $scope.list = response.data;
            //    })
            //}

        })

    //custDetailController Ends 
.factory('FileUploadService', function ($http, $q) { // explained abour controller and service in part 2
    var fac = {};
    fac.UploadFile = function (Name, DoB, Phone, EMail, Description, Gender, Photo) {
        var formData = new FormData();

        //We can send more data to server using append         
        formData.append("Name", Name);
        formData.append("DoB", DoB);
        formData.append("Phone", Phone);
        formData.append("EMail", EMail);
        formData.append("Description", Description);
        formData.append("Gender", Gender);
        formData.append("Photo", Photo);

        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.post("/Home/SaveFiles", formData,
            {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            })
        .success(function (d) {
            defer.resolve(d);
        })
        .error(function (f) {
            defer.reject(f);
        });

        return defer.promise;

    }
    return fac;

});
```

But when I build and run the code No values comes in Drop Down List. How can I populate Drop Down?

Comment: Can you log `console.log(data)` in your `success` (which should actually be `then`) and see if you are getting any data back from you BE? Also where does `GetLocList()` gets called from?

Comment: I want to call it automatically on page load.

Comment: So WHERE does it get called from? Your code does not show where the call happens, if that's the case your function is never used thus no data returned.

Comment: I got your your point. I'm new to angular. Please suggest how can I call it automatically on page load?

Comment: Assuming your controller fires correctly just add a `()` after your closing `}` in the function. As in `function GetLocList() { //some code here }();`

Comment: Two Errors:- 1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) 2. Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module custFormApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'custFormApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Can you share the entire angular controller in your question pls.

Comment: I've edited my question. One more thing I'm getting Syntax Error when I changed  function GetLocList() {//mycodehere} to function GetLocList() {//mycodehere}();

Comment: does your `alert(data)` show anything?

Comment: Nothing. I guess the function is not firing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136325/discussion-between-jax-and-deepak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution with the help of @Jax. I changed the CustForm.js file as:-

```js
 $scope.GetLocList = function () {
                $http({
                    method: 'Get',
                    url: '/Home/GetLocList'
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.location = data;
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
                });
            }

            $scope.GetLocList();
```

Don't forget to add $http in Angular Controller. Changed my Html as:-

```html
 <select ng-model="CustLoc" ng-options="l.LocName for l in location track by l.Id">
                                <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="(f1.uCustLoc.$dirty || f1.$submitted) && f1.uCustLoc.$error.required">Location required!</span>
```

Finally My C# code is:-

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetLocList()
    {
        //IEnumerable<LocationTbl> ie = (from d in db.LocationTbls
        //                              select d).ToList();

        var ret = db.LocationTbls.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.LocName }).ToList();

        return Json(ret,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```